# React.js too many rerenders don't know why

Tags: reactjs

I am making a chess game and now i have tried to make squares but it says "too many rerenders" I think I only made 64 rerenders is it above the limit?
because its not infinite rerenders

````
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  const horizontalLine = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
  const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
  console.log(horizontalLine)
  console.log(verticalLine)


  const [square, setSquare] = useState({
    id: "",
    ver: "",
    hor: ""
  })

  

  const squares = [verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
    horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
      setSquare(`${verticals+horizontals}`),
      setSquare(`${verticals}`),
      setSquare(`${horizontals}`),
      console.log(square)
    ))
  ))]
  console.log(square)
  console.log(squares)


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App```
````

Comment: You're updating state on every render, and updating state triggers a re-render.  It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish in the `const squares = ...` operation, but this is most certainly not the way to do it.  (Even if this *did* work, it wouldn't make much sense.  You'd be updating state 192 times, each over-writing the previous one, each to a single string value.  At the end of all of that the state would be a single string value.  Likely just the value `"8"`.)

Comment: *its not infinite rerenders* - it is though. `squares` gets re-defined every render and remaps over the lines and sets state. This causes a re-render which starts all over again

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do anything remotely close to what you're expecting:

```
const squares = [verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
    horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
      setSquare(`${verticals+horizontals}`),
      setSquare(`${verticals}`),
      setSquare(`${horizontals}`),
      console.log(square)
    ))
  ))]
```

What this *does* do is perform two nested loops (a `.map()` operation iterates over an array), updates state three times therein (so 192 times total), logs the same unchanging value to the console (64 times), and returns a nested array of `undefined` values to `squares`.

It *looks like* the intent is for `squares` to contain data like:

```
[
  [
    [
      { id: "a1", ver: "a", hor: "1" },
      { id: "a2", ver: "a", hor: "2" },
      { id: "a3", ver: "a", hor: "3" },
      //etc...
    ],
    [
      { id: "b1", ver: "b", hor: "1" },
      { id: "b2", ver: "b", hor: "2" },
      { id: "b3", ver: "b", hor: "3" },
      //etc...
    ],
    //etc...
  ]
]
```

If that's the case then you don't want `setSquare` *or* `console.log` in this operation.  You want to `return` the *object* that you're trying to build.  For example:

```js
const horizontalLine = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];

const squares = [verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
  horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
    {
      id: `${verticals+horizontals}`,
      ver: `${verticals}`,
      hor: `${horizontals}`
    }
  ))
))];

console.log(squares);
```

Note how state isn't involved in this at all.  In fact, I'd even recommend taking this a step further and defining these static, hard-coded values *outside* of the component so you don't need to re-calculate this nested array on every render:

```
import "./App.css";

const horizontalLine = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
const squares = [verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
  horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
    {
      id: `${verticals+horizontals}`,
      ver: `${verticals}`,
      hor: `${horizontals}`
    }
  ))
))];

function App() {
  const [square, setSquare] = useState({
    id: "",
    ver: "",
    hor: ""
  });

  // presumably something will use the above state eventually...
  return (
    <div className='App'>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

*As an aside... Please start adopting the habit of terminating statements with semi-colons.  Otherwise you are very likely to encounter strange bugs in the future.*